# Move Google maps map to right through protractor js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am using protractor to test my angularjs application built with [ng-map](http://ngmap.github.io/) for google maps directive.

In the test, I could zoom in/out but clicking on +/- visible in the maps.
However, to pan the map, there are no controls in Google Maps Javascript API v3.

So I thought of sending a **right arrow key event** to the browser to simulate the panning towards East direction.

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_RIGHT).perform();
browser.sleep(5000); // To hold the browser to notice the change.
```

However, when I run it, I do not see any change in the view of the Map.

Comment: Did you click on the map first to give it focus, before performing the right arrow?

Comment: @Gunderson Thanks it worked !! How can I mark your comment as an answer ?

Comment: Awesome!  Heh no problem, I suppose I can post as an answer though I don't have much explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this in the comments above -- I tried manually on our app which uses google maps, sending a right arrow should work after giving the map focus.  So my suggestion is to try clicking on the map first before performing the right arrow.

```
var map = element(by.css('div.google-map'));
map.click(); // give the map focus
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_RIGHT).perform(); // move map
browser.sleep(5000); // To hold the browser to notice the change.
```